# Does "Magic Numbers" weaken encryption?

Tags: encryption, attacks, file-encryption

I was wandering at superuser and I found this question: [Compress and then encrypt, or vice-versa?](https://superuser.com/questions/257782/compress-and-then-encrypt-or-vice-versa)

Nearly all files have a [Magic Number](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File_format#Magic_number) at a certain position in them. So, I wonder if I can *attack* (to break encryption or reduce possiblities...) by guessing several popular file formats?

I am aware that my question is very general without mentioning any encryption method or file format but I'm also looking for a general answer.

Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Trying to use the encrypted and plain "magic numbers" to figure out the key is a type of [known-plaintext attack](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Known-plaintext_attack).  Modern encryption algorithms are highly resistant to this sort of thing -- typically, trying every possible key is the only known way to do it.

Magic numbers and other file structure makes it easier for an attacker to tell that their latest guess at the key was correct, but they don't reduce the number of guesses needed.

Answer (score 0):

Not if the encryption is done correctly. What does "correctly" entail?

1. A good, modern cipher is being used. The standard choice today is AES.
2. Under most circumstances, *authentication* in the form of a [MAC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Message_authentication_code) is required as well. Without authentication, ciphertext is malleable. An attacker can modify bits of the ciphertext to say whatever he wants when it's decrypted. This is made much easier when there is data in a fixed position (say in the case of Magic Numbers of a file or a HTTP header).

Comment: Note that in the real world, malleability can be very hard to exploit.  For example, generating a valid PNG header has a complexity upwards of 2^96: 12 of the first 16 bytes of the file are fixed, and the remaining four are restricted by the length of the file.

Comment: @Mark Depends on the cipher. With a stream cipher (or CTR or OFB modes of a block cipher, which just makes a stream cipher), it's quite easy to exploit.

Comment: `Without encryption` - do you mean without a MAC?

Comment: @SilverlightFox Yes, my bad. :)